# Error PLS-00103 when using revoke inside a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, compiler-errors

It seems I'm missing something. I can't seem to use revoke inside a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE revokeRight 
AS 
BEGIN
    REVOKE ALL ON Barang FROM WorkerA;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly use REVOKE statement inside PL/SQL block, you need to use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE**:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE revokeRight 
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE ALL ON Barang FROM WorkerA';
END;
/
```

I would not recommend to use DCL commands inside PL/SQL to grant/revoke on the fly. You need to be cautious before doing so.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it worked. It should be fine though, I'm just doing this for an assignment.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: @LalitKumarB I don't think the semicolon inside the dynamic string should be there. Oracle SQL has no semicolon.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yeah, that's a typo. Thanks for pointing that out.